# How to use Pandas sep when including time information?

Tags: python, pandas

RAW:

```
Jan 11 17:23:47 JACK
FEB 12 12:41:12 EMILIY
```

Want:

```
           Time Name
Jan 11 17:23:47 JACK
FEB 12 12:41:12 EMILIY
```

import pandas as pd

HOW TO(??):

```
import pandas as pd
ex = ['timestamp', 'name']
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.log', delimiter='??', comment='#', engine='python', names=ex)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: It seems like you are looking to rename the columns of the data frame. Here is a link to the documentation. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: pass `header=None` in `read_csv()` then after reading file use `df.columns=ex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dd1.csv",delimiter=" ",header=None) 
#Reading csv by setting space separator and None header
"""
Jan 11 17:23:47 JACK
FEB 12 12:41:12 EMILIY
"""

df.columns=["Month","Day","time","Name"]
# Setting column name

df["Time"]=df.apply(lambda x: f"{x.Month} {x.Day} {x.time}",axis=1)
# Combining columns

df=df.drop(columns=["Day","time","Month"],axis=1)
# Droping now not nesssary columns

print(df)
"""
     Name             Time
0    JACK  Jan 11 17:23:47
1  EMILIY  FEB 12 12:41:12
"""
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It fits exactly for me

Comment: @matiii If it worked for you then, you can mark this as accepted answer. And if you like my effort then, you may upvote it. Anyway happy coding. :)